# How to supply data for search bar suggestions

Tags: react-native, api, txt, searchbar

Basically I'm working on my personal project, and I'm building a react native app that serves a very similar purpose to that of eBay's or Gumtree or the like. Users can obviously search for a product, I want to show search suggestions based on what the user types. Search engines usually show suggestions based on what is also being searched by other users, or what data is already is already posted on the site.

Since this is a personal project neither of those two cases apply. I need a way to still provide suggestions to user searches.

One way I tried doing this, is by finding a txt file with a bunch of product names and filtering through that based on user search.

I tried doing the same approach but by using an API instead of a text file.

I couldn't find any resources for either of those 2 methods, so I don't really know what to do

Any suggestions or references to material would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you currently storing your product data for your app?

Comment: @server_unknown I plan on storing it in a DB, but that hasn't been developed yet. Still developing the frontend